# what happens to a rust mutable value after each assignment

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutable

Here are two examples of dynamic mutable value.

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("Hello");
    println!("{}", x);

    x = format!("{x}, world!");
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

So as you can see, we have a mutable variable `x`. `x` gets borrowed by `format!` & turns to a new value that is then assigned back to `x`.

```rust
pub fn main() {
    let mut x = String::from("Hello, world!");
    println!("{}", x);

    x = String::from("Lorem, ipsum!");
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

My real problem is this code, where the value assigned to `x` has no connection with it's initial value. Variables can only take owner-ship over a single value, so how does Rust keep track of "Hello, world!" & "Lorem, ipsum!"? Exactly what happens to mutable values after assignments?

My guess is that it checks if the value getting assigned to depends on the first one, if yes, it won't drop it.

Comment: The original value of `x` gets dropped in both of these cases. The return value of `format!` does not hold a reference to its parameters, it creates a new `String`.

Comment: What happens on a case that would borrow , instead of cloning?

Comment: In the case that the parameters of `format!` are borrowed? It still constructs a new `String` value that does not hold those references.

Comment: @pigeonhands What about the case where `x = takes_ownership_and_gives_back(x)`, would it still drop?

Comment: No it would not be dropped. Values are dropped when they no longer have an owner.

Comment: [If the new value borrows from the old value, that's an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21940847c78f416b088e22624d6527d9).